# how to SSH connection between two ubuntu machines which one of them doesn't have internet?

Tags: ssh, beagleboard

I have a ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine which able to cennect internet and a beagleboard-xm that includes ubuntu 13.10 os without any internet connection. I want to connect with ssh into the beagleboard-xm.

I tried many options and didn't get any results. Please help me.

Thanks, regards

Mustafa

Edit: Thank you Hatef for your answer, and i used ethernet (cat) cable. I found a page http://anwaarullah.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/direct-access-raspberry-pi-shell-and-desktop/ which wanna do the same operation with me but with just one different part, they use rasberry-pi instead of beagleboard-xm. I applied what there is written and i can now able to connect with ssh into the beagleboard. But i give the ip to beagleboard with sudo ifconfig eth0 x.x.x.x command using serial terminal and i finally connected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an Ethernet cable between two devices and sharing the internet connection of your Ubuntu (via IPforwarding) with the Beagleboard.
Also make sure the SSH option is enabled in the Beagleboard! I know for the RPI you can enable it by using a HDMI cable and connecting to a TV with HDMI input support.